# How to verify upward teleport on Relay Chain?

Tags: parachain, xcm, events, teleport

I performed an upward teleport from `Encointer-Parachain` to `Kusama- Relay Chain`.

The `parachain` confirmed the XCM extrinsic `polkadotXcm.limitedTeleportAssets` and an Event was disposed: `polkadotXcm.Attempted` with

```
{
  Complete: 2,000,000,000
}
```

And the balance was deducted indeed.

I see that the balance on the relaychain is correct now (it increased by the expected amount). But is there an Event to listen to to detect that the teleport was successful?

I tried a subscan search for palletXCM events:
https://kusama.subscan.io/event?address=&module=xcmpallet&event=all&startDate=&endDate=&startBlock=&endBlock=&timeType=date&version=9170

But that wont yield an Event for my upwards teleport

Answer (score 7):

We have built this tool to find XCM events cross different chains https://parachain-utilities.vercel.app/xcm

Code: https://github.com/AcalaNetwork/parachain-utilities/blob/3b1a1f6add16a66f9995dfe4fa70fe6ede31b2f4/src/components/Xcm/Xcm.tsx#L118

It basically tries search relaychain blocks to look for relevant events and decode it.

More description can be found here: https://github.com/AcalaNetwork/parachain-utilities/issues/8

Answer (score 4):

This is currently fiddlier than it needs to be. There will be a `Balances.Deposit` event citing the credited account (along with the normal XCM stuff, like `Xcm.UpwardMessageProcessed`), but for now you need to index both chaning and find the hash of each incoming message and match it with the hashes of outgoing messages.
There's some work under way in `sidecar` related to this: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/issues/732